# Why is this mutator method returning an error even after calling it?

Tags: java, bluej

I have called 'setPrice()' mutator method from a class 'Holiday' which holds 'double' as a data type. However, when I add 'holiday.setPrice()', it says "method setPrice in Holiday class cannot be applied to the given types: double". I am confused to why that is.

```
public void checkOut(Member member, Holiday holiday){
        if(member.getBalance() >= holiday.getPrice()){
            System.out.println("Transaction complete"); 
            System.out.println("You have been automatically logged off");
             member.setLoginStatus(false);
             if(checkHitDiscount() == true){
             holiday.setPrice() = discount - holiday.getPrice() ;
             System.out.println(" Good news! You're eligible for a discount!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("No discount available, try again next time");
            }
        } else { 
                System.out.println("You don't have suffiencient funds");
            }
    }
```

Comment: please try that: `holiday.setPrice(discount - holiday.getPrice());` You couldn't  assign something for returned value

Comment: also maybe it should be holiday.getPrice()-discount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use the following line:

```
holiday.setPrice() = discount - holiday.getPrice();
```

This should probably be

```
holiday.setPrice(discount - holiday.getPrice());
```

instead.  The inputs of a function go inside its parentheses.

EDIT: `discount` and `holiday.getPrice()` should also probably be reversed, based on their names.

EDIT2: What your existing code is trying to do is assign the value of `discount - holiday.getPrice()` to the double which is returned by a hypothetical `holiday.setPrice()` with no inputs.  This is not allowed, because that is a value, not a variable (ie: a name referring to a spot in memory storing a value).  It's a bit like trying to execute `5 = 3 + 4`;.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now. Appreciate the help

Comment: @ThaboStephaniousEberhart You should probably mark the answer as accepted, then, for anyone who comes along later.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer